# How to use rolling log using log4c?

Tags: c, logging

Can someone tell me how I can use the rolling log feature of [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/) API library?

There is only documentation on the functions it provides and there are so many.

If anyone has used rolling log with [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/), would be great to see how to configure it and use it.

Answer (score 11):

Add something like this to your `.log4crc` file:

```
<rollingpolicy name="myrollingpolicy" 
               type="sizewin"
               maxsize="1024"
               maxnum="10"
               />
<appender name="myrollingfileappender"
          type="rollingfile"
          logdir="."
          prefix="myprefix"
          layout="dated"
          rollingpolicy="myrollingpolicy"
          />
```

Then you do logging like normal with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "log4c.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int rc = 0;
  log4c_category_t* mycat = NULL;

  if (log4c_init()) {
    printf("log4c_init() failed");
    rc = 1;  
  } 
  else{
      mycat = log4c_category_get("log4c.examples.helloworld");

      log4c_category_log(mycat, LOG4C_PRIORITY_ERROR, "Hello World!");

    /* Explicitly call the log4c cleanup routine */
    if ( log4c_fini()){
      printf("log4c_fini() failed");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is all available in the examples from the [log4c source code](http://log4c.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/log4c/log4c/)

Comment: Helpful, thanks, and good luck for your "neuromancer" badge ;-)

Comment: Can the file name contain the pid of the running process?

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a 3 month old question, just wondering if the Wikipedia page was tried -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4c#Development_with_Log4C.

Comment: Wikipeia redirects to Log4J. They are similar, but not the same. Therefore, there are minimal differences.